# OpenCL Nested Kernels

Tags: c, kernel, opencl, reduce, pyopencl

I have a nxnxm ndarray that I would like to reduce down the m-axis. pyopencl has a built in ReductionKernel that is the following:

```
class pyopencl.reduction.ReductionKernel(ctx, dtype_out, neutral, reduce_expr, map_expr=None, arguments=None, name="reduce_kernel", options=[], preamble="")
```

If written the following way, it successfully sums a single vector down to a scalar:

```
krnl = ReductionKernel(context, numpy.float32, neutral="0",reduce_expr="a+b", map_expr="x[i]", arguments="__global float *x")
sum_A = krnl(d_A).get()
```

where sum_A is a float and d_A is the vector on device memory.

I'd like to call this kernel and pass a m-length column for each index in the nxn matrix. My strategy was to pass the entire nxnxm ndarray to a parent kernel and then use `enqueue_kernel` pass an array to `ReductionKernel` but I'm unsure of how the syntax works in terms of receiving the sum. By the way, the matrix is already in row-order so the m-length arrays are already contiguous.

```
__kernel reduce(global float* input, 
                global float* output,
                const unsigned int m, 
                const unsigned int n)
{
    const int i = get_global_id(0);
    const int j = get_global_id(1);

    float array[m];

    //Initialize an array of input[i*m+j*m*n] to input[i*m+j*m*n + m]
    for(k = 0, k < m, k++)
    {
        array[k] = input[i*m+j*m*n+k];
    }

    //enqueue ReductionKernel with this array
    //Place result in output[i*n+j]
}
```

Comment: What is your question? The only thing that appears question-like is the part about receiving the sum. Kernels don't return values, so the only way to receive the sum is to write it into memory. Please note that nested kernels best used when you don't know the additional work until the early kernels run. If you know the entire volume of your work from the start, it doesn't seem like you need nested kernels.

Comment: @Dithermaster My question is the proper syntax and way to use `enqueueKernel` in this scenario. But if you think I don't need nested kernels at all then I'd be very open to a new algorithm.